# CGColorSpace name profile

Tags: swift, uicolor, color-profile, cgcolorspace

```swift
let red = UIColor.red
print(red.cgColor.colorSpace!)
```

The output is
`<CGColorSpace 0x60000332d260> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1; extended range)`.

How can I get the single values like profile the name `sRGB IEC61966-2.1` as string?

Comment: What you referring is ICC profile and iOS does not have public API to get ICC Profile tags (only opaque data from CGColorSpaceCopyICCData), so you might find useful 3d-party libraries, like https://sourceforge.net/projects/sampleicc/, if you really need that info (why? all system colors are in sRGB - it is documented). Please note that ICC profile is optional and might be absent in colorspace.

Comment: Maybe it's the only road but uphill. In 2021 with the evolution that has made iOS, padOS and the quality of displays that support much wider color spaces than sRGB, it is absurd that there are not yet all the macOS APIs. Even just to get a profile name like sRGB or DisplayP3!

Comment: Tell that to Apple ))

Comment: Already done! I doubt to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, I think, it solves your problem:

```
let color = UIColor.red
let value = String(describing: color.cgColor.colorSpace)
let profileName = value.split(separator: ";")[2].trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
print(profileName)
```

> sRGB IEC61966-2.1

Comment: As Asperi noted here there is no public API from Apple to get ICC Profile tags. I appreciate the attempt anyway!